# Bug with jquery-mobile: listview('refresh') and buttons, on Opera Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, opera, opera-mobile

I'm testing jquery-mobile with Opera Mobile browser. There are bugs, which are visible on both Opera Mobile Emulator and Opera Mobile on mobile device. On both they are occuring randomly (often, but not always).

The most visible is with refreshing list with `listview('refresh');` call. Sometimes the changes are not visible, and the pure HTML before the modifications is displayed. But after tapping the device the changes became visible.

And also, some clicks on buttons does not work. Most of the time it works, but sometimes the button need to be pressed a few times.

JQuery version is 1.6.4, jquery-mobile version is 1.0.

Did you find similar bugs, or know what is causing them and how to prevent them? I think that jQuery-mobile is using some unstandard behaviour, which is working on other browsers, but is causing bug under Opera, because most of the apps works fine, but *some* are causing problems only under Opera/Opera Mobile.

Comment: Not sure how well Opera is supported http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/ could you add errors/warnings/code examples you're trying?

Comment: Can you share a link to a test case?

Comment: This is an intranet application...

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to jQuery Mobile 1.0.1?

Comment: I have information that in jquery 1.1.0 this error has not been seen.